# Using rvalue references for default arguments

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, default-arguments

I want to make a function that takes an optional reference to an object, and creates one for the duration of the function if it is not provided, i.e.

```
void Foo(Bar& b = Bar()) { /* stuff */ }
```

This is, of course, invalid code, as a `Bar` cannot be implicitly converted to a `Bar` reference in this context. The reference can't be `const`, as `b` is mutated inside the function.

You can get around this by using an rvalue reference, i.e.

```
void Foo(Bar&& b = Bar()) { /* stuff */ }
```

Is this a valid use of rvalue references? Callers now have to call `std::move` on their `Bar` arguments, even though I have no intention of clearing the passed `Bar`, as is usually the case when you are passing rvalues.

Comment: Why don't you just use a static default-object?

Comment: How about `void Foo(Bar & b = stay(Bar()))`? With `template <typename T> T & stay(T && t) { return t; }`.

Comment: @Deduplicator perhaps the constructor is non-trivial

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Sorry, but I don't quite see how the ctor (and maybe also the dtor) being non-trivial has any bearing on the use of a static default object except in contrived edge-cases (static-initialization-order fiasco). Could you elaborate?

Comment: In the static version the constructor only runs once for the course of the program , but OP's sample code has it run for every invocation of the function

Comment: @MattMcNabb: That might be "good enough", in which case it is the best solution.

Comment: Why do you mention universal references in the title, when this has nothing to do with them? Also, "shallow copying" is a _really_ misleading term to use for move semantics.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: What to "universal references" generally refer to? I was under the impression that they are synonymous to rvalue references and were simply the name [preferred by Scott Meyers](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers). Also, could you elaborate on how a shallow copy is misleading when it comes to move semantics?

Comment: @MattKline: Universal references are reference parameters that match rvalues, lvalues, const rvalues, or const lvalues.  They are template functions that receive the template type as `&&`.  It's counterintuitive, because they have _no relation with rvalue reference parameters which _also_ use `&&` in their signature.

Comment: "It's counterintuitive" And how. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @MattKline, as stated above, universal references are only visually the same as rvalue references, they are semantically very different, read the article you linked to. A move is a move, not a copy, "shallow copying" does not imply anything about modifying the source object, which is a key part of move semantics. Using the right terminology is important to avoid confusing readers and yourself about the concepts you're referring to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
void Foo(Bar&& b = Bar()) { /* stuff */ }
```

That's certainly a valid use of r-value references, but it does not in any way reflect the actual semantics, and is thus "broken by design".

What you want to do, is use a forwarder-function supplying the default argument like this:

```
void Foo(Bar& b) { /* stuff */ }
void Foo() { Bar b{}; Foo(b); }
```

Or use a static default-argument (Beware that this always reuses the same object):

```
template<class T> decltype(T{})& default_object() {static T x{}; return x;}
void Foo(Bar& b = default_object<Bar>()) { /* stuff */ }
```

Or [like KerrekSB proposes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253065/using-rvalue-universal-references-for-default-arguments/25253182#comment39345163_25253065) (I added `constexpr`) use this **dangerous** template function:

```
template<class T> constexpr T& no_move(T&& t) { return t; }
void Foo(Bar& b = no_move(Bar{})) { /* stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 9):

So you have a function that takes an in-out parameter that it is going to modify to pass back information to the caller.

But you want the parameter to be optional.

So your solution is to make the parameter appear to be an in parameter, by requiring callers to move arguments (which would usually mean they lost whatever state they had or may be in an unspecified state). That is a bad, bad design. You will confuse callers with a weird API created for the convenience of the function's internal implementation. You should design APIs for the users, not the implementors.

You can either do what Deduplicator suggests and split it into two functions, one that provides a dummy object to be provided as the in-out parameter and then discarded:

```
void Foo(Bar& b) { /* stuff */ }
void Foo() { Bar dummy{}; Foo(dummy); }
```

or since what you seem to want is a reference that can be null, stop using a reference and use the right language feature for passing something by reference that can be null instead:

```
void Foo(Bar* b) { /* stuff, updating b if not null */ }
```

Comment: Certainly also a valid option. Might be cleaner, or might not. +1 BTW: I listed two options you didn't mention.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I didn't like the other two options so didn't refer to them :) You got my upvote for the overloaded function suggestion.